# Why does including fftw3.h header file work with angle brackets but not quotes?

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, include

First of all, I understand the difference between using angle brackets to include files and using quotes. Namely, that angle brackets make the preprocessor search for the file in an implementation dependent manner, and using quotes means the preprocessor searches first in the project directory, then in the search path used for the #include  form. I understand the difference, but my question is about *why* the "implementation dependent manner" of searching for files included by angle brackets is not working for me when it has always worked before.

I am trying to compile and run a c++ code. I type in the command line the following:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=gcc-11 ..
make
```

It starts to compile, then I get the following error:

```
/Users/[me]/Desktop/cosmograph/ICs/../utils/Fourier.h:9:10: fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <fftw3.h>
```

Now I have fftw installed via homebrew, and it is up to date. I tried reinstalling it as well. I can see that it is located on my machine in `/usr/local/opt/fftw` and also `/usr/local/Cellar/fftw`. I was able to find a work-around by just copying the header file from `/usr/local/Cellar/fftw/3.3.9_1/include/fftw3.h` to the project directory, and changing `#include <fftw3.h>` to `#include "fftw3.h"`.

Here is my main problem- why does including it with quotes work but brackets doesn't? I believe I have the right directories in my PATH:

```
echo $PATH
/anaconda3/bin:/Users/[me]/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/[me]/opt/bin:usr/local:/usr/local/Cellar:/usr/local/include:/usr/local/include/
```

This is still a problem because the compiler is now getting hung up on the same issue later in the code. I am getting this error now:

```
/Users/[me]/Desktop/cosmograph/components/static/static_ic.cc:8:10: fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/spherical_harmonic.hpp: No such file or directory
    8 | #include <boost/math/special_functions/spherical_harmonic.hpp>
```

I have boost installed by homebrew, and that particular file it's trying to include is located at: `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/math/special_functions/spherical_harmonic.hpp`. I can do the same workaround here and include that file by writing:

```
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/math/special_functions/spherical_harmonic.hpp"
```

but then I have a problem because the `spherical_harmonic.h` file, like many files in the boost library, includes other files in the boost library by using brackets. I really would rather not go through every file that I need to include and change the #include lines to use quotes instead of brackets.

I have also tried doing the following:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=gcc-11 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/fftw/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/" ..
make
```

but it doesn't help, I get the same resulting error.

I guess I think it must be some problem with my path, but I'm really scratching my head over this one. Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm using a mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: In general, any header that's not part of the compiler should be pulled in with quotes.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure, that makes sense. But I've installed the Boost library which contains many files which have headers included with angle brackets. Since including files by angle brackets is not working for me, I'm not able to include any of the boost files without going through each one and changing the #include lines. Again, this is a problem I've not had before, so I would like to get to the root of what may be causing it.

Comment: I think your problem description `"why does including it with quotes work but brackets doesn't?"` is rather misleading.  It only works `with quotes` *after* you've manually copied the header to a specific directory.  What is the absolute path to the `fftw3.h` file you wish to include?  You need to adjust the `-I...` options passed to the compiler/preprocesor to include the directory that contains that file.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your comment, you're right the way I wrote the question is a little misleading. I was trying to figure out a way to adjust the `-I...` options but calling cmake with `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= "-I..."` didn't work so I was stuck. For anyone wondering, I eventually was able to compile the code by writing `find_package(Boost REQUIRED) \n include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and changing the compiler being used from gcc to g++. Still not sure exactly why it didn't work the other way.